# Modifying all the string primitives in a JSON structure

Tags: java, json

In Java, given a textual representation of a JSON object, how can I apply a function only to leaves that are strings?

For example, converting all the string values to upper case:
Input:

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "address": {
        "street": "elm",
        "number": 4
    },
    "children": ["george", "paul"]
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "name": "JOHN",
    "address": {
        "street": "ELM"
        "number": 4
    },
    "children": ["GEORGE", "PAUL"]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do it in any particular language? Or just a general algorithm?

Comment: I want to do it in Java.

Answer (score 3):

use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (or any other json parser) to parse the data into `Map`, remove the non strings, serialize back to json using Gson